# How to select a often used css class within a div

Tags: html, css

What do i have to write to my css code to select .formlabel class within formblock2, for example to change the color of Heading B to green instead of red?

```css
.formlabel {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="form">
<div class="formblock1">
<div class="formlabel">Heading A
</div>
</div>
<div class="formblock2">
<div class="formlabel">Heading B
</div>
</div>
<div class="formblock3">
<div class="formlabel">Heading C
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call the parent of it then call the div that you want like this.

```css
.formlabel {color:red;}

.formblock2 > .formlabel {color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="form">
<div class="formblock1">
<div class="formlabel">Heading A
</div>
</div>
<div class="formblock2">
<div class="formlabel">Heading B
</div>
</div>
<div class="formblock3">
<div class="formlabel">Heading C
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx! that was what i was looking for. Never understood the syntax for this, do you have a tip what resource i can read or what i have to search for to get knowledge about the use of the > ?

Comment: an arrow greater than is a selector with a specific parent of a child you are calling on css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors heres a link where you can learn how to use selectors. you can accept teh answer by clicking check beside the answer so people can see that your problem were resolved happy coding :)